# How can I select a max of column which type is unique identifier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a structure as bellow

```
create table shpro(
    Gid uniqueidentifier,
    id int,
    prod varchar(30),
    orderdate datetime,
    shipdate datetime
    )
```

i want to get the max of the orderdate and shipdate and also removing the duplicate data i tried the query as bellow

```
select
        MAX(p1.Gid) Gid,
        MAX(p1.id) id,
        MAX(p1.prod) prod,
        MAX(p1.orderdate) orderdate,
        MAX(p2.shipdate) shipdate
 from shpro p1 inner join shpro p2
on p1.id=p2.id
where cast(p1.orderdate as DATE)>GETDATE() and cast(p1.shipdate as DATE)<GETDATE()-1
group by p1.prod
```

I have got the error **Operand data type `uniqueidentifier` is invalid for `max` operator.**

what i did is trying to convert the column with `uniqueidentifier` to `varchar` OR `BINARY` i tried the query as bellow

```
select
        MAX(cast(p1.Gid as varchar(36))) Gid,
        MAX(p1.id) id,
        MAX(p1.prod) prod,
        MAX(p1.orderdate) orderdate,
        MAX(p2.shipdate) shipdate
 from shpro p1 inner join shpro p2
on p1.id=p2.id
where cast(p1.orderdate as DATE)>GETDATE() and cast(p1.shipdate as DATE)<GETDATE()-1
group by p1.prod
```

it give me a result but it's a wrong result

I have an idea using `CTE` but i want something without using `CTE`

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Selecting  MAX(p1.Gid) and MAX(p1.id) doesn't seem to make sense, why do you select it? You want to select orders with max orderdate and ship date?

Comment: just to use a `group by` if i didn't use this i thins i can't do a `group by` yes to second `query` it's returns me a result

Comment: So you want a simple query + max for dates, am I right?

Comment: Exactly but using a `group by` of the `column prod` for not have duplicate `data`

Answer (score 3):

"Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for max operator" is key, it's telling you that max(uniqueidentifier) isn't supported. Either upgrade to a version that supports this or cast to varchar inside the max, which is slower.

e.g. MS SQL 2008 R2 will throw this error where as MS SQL 2012 doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand You clearly, here is how you may get MAX() for orderdate and ship data among other select results:

```
SELECT
    p1.Gid,
    p1.id,
    MAX(p1.orderdate) OVER (PARTITION BY p1.prod) AS max_orderdate,
    MAX(p2.shipdate) OVER (PARTITION BY p1.prod) AS max_shipdate
FROM shpro AS p1 INNER JOIN shpro AS p2
        ON p1.id = p2.id
WHERE
    cast(p1.orderdate AS DATE) > GETDATE() AND cast(p1.shipdate AS DATE) < GETDATE() - 1
```